# Printing after a countdown in Java

Tags: java, timer

I want to print after my countdown. I already have it printing before the countdown, but I need now to print it after. I've tried putting it in many places, but I don't know where to put System.out.println(addition); which is the total value of the equation.
     Thanks

```
 Here's the code 

     import java.util.Timer; 
     import java.util.TimerTask;  
     public class S1p4 { 

     public static void main(String[] args) { 
     Timer timer = new Timer(); 
     Task task = new Task(); 
     timer.schedule(task, 1000, 1000); 

     int num1 = (int) (Math.random()*10); 

     int num2 = (int) (Math.random()*10); 

     int addition = (int) num1 + num2; 

     System.out.println (num1); 

     System.out.println("+"); 

     System.out.println (num2); 


     } 
     } 

     class Task extends TimerTask { 

     int i=4; 
     @Override 
     public void run() { 
     i--; 
     if(i==3) 
     System.out.println("3>>>"); 
     if(i==2){ 
     System.out.println("2>>>"); 
     } 
     if(i==1){ 
     System.out.println("1>>>"); 
     cancel(); 

     System.exit(0); 
     } 

     } 

     }
```

Comment: Please properly indent your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this. Note that I added the result to the constructor of `Task`, and I added the `System.out.println` before exit.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class S1p4 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    int num1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    int num2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    int addition = (int) num1 + num2;
    System.out.println(num1);
    System.out.println("+");
    System.out.println(num2);
    // Add the result to the task.
    Task task = new Task(addition);
    timer.schedule(task, 1000, 1000);
  }
}

class Task extends TimerTask {
  // Store the result.
  private int result;

  // Construct a Task with the result.
  public Task(int result) {
    super();
    this.result = result;
  }

  // How many times to run.
  int i = 4;

  @Override
  public void run() {
    i--;
    if (i == 3) {
      System.out.println("3>>>");
    } else if (i == 2) {
      System.out.println("2>>>");
    } else {
      System.out.println("1>>>");
      cancel();
      // The timer is done print the result.
      System.out.println("The result was " + result);
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }
}
```